# How can I run Ubuntu server 20.10 in RAM?

Tags: server, ssd, ram, nvme

I would like to run my Ubuntu server in ram, is that possible? If so how do i get started?

I have 64 GB of RAM

1TB pcie gen 4 nvme m2 with Linux Ubuntu 20.10 server

1tb SSD not yet setup

2x2tb hdd not yet setup

I want the highest possible performance. Am i right in thinking running the entire thing in ram would achieve better performance compared to normal storage

I know my specs are more than 'adequate' however i want to get the best performance from my machine.

I know its volatile...

I plan to use the server as a cryptocurrency miner to test my hashrate in mining compared to my previous setup...

Dont forget - anything is possible!

Comment: [Two possibilities are outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212927/1091774). That said, I do not believe that having the entire OS in a RAM disk would result in greater performance. Having just the `/home` directory might, assuming that is where you are storing the hashing data.

Comment: It mentions nothing would be persistent.  Thats fine i guess except for the fact that i need the entire blockchain of the cryptocurrency loaded in order to check my hashrate. Would i be able to store data to another storage device ? One which has the capacity for the entire blockchain...

Comment: You said quite clearly that you "know it's volatile", so there's certainly a risk that you could waste valuable hashing time redownloading the blockchain. That said, you could look at mirroring the RAM disk to a local NVMe, then using option 2 when booting to `rsync` the data back. Alternatively, you could spend 0.25BTC on some non-volatile RAM if your motherboard supports it, though I have never dabbled with that type of memory so can't say if it'll suit this particular purpose.