# Moving home folder from Ubuntu 20.04 to new installation of 22.04 on a different SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I have two SSDs connected to my laptop.  The old 500 GB Samsung has my Ubuntu 20.04, GRUB and partition for files.
I have a new 1TB SSD also connected on which I want to install Ubuntu 22.04.
The issue for me is that my "old" 20.04 has many programs and tweaks which I want to keep.
I saw this: [Moving home folder to new installation of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812675/moving-home-folder-to-new-installation-of-ubuntu)
Will it work for an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04?

Comment: Several tweaks and extension are not compatible/available for 22.04 as of now. You might want to check whether those you want to migrate over are usable on 22.04 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend doing this.

Copying your home folder from your 20.04 installation to your 22.04 installation will *not* preserve your applications (because applications are not installed in your home folder).

Also, it will not retain all of your configurations. This is because some of the configuration keys and values have changed between 20.04 and 22.04. For example, there is a new configuration to allow a different background for dark vs. light mode.

As an other example, extensions you have installed in 20.04 may not work on 22.04 because Ubuntu 22.04 requires newer versions of those extensions and their configurations. Not all extensions that are available for 20.04 are available or work on 22.04.

Comment: I decided on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on the new SSD.  It is now installed and GRUB shows both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS's which I can log into.  Which folders do I copy and how so that my new Ubuntu is as close to a "clone" as it can get to the old one?  Is there a definite authority website or resource?

Comment: Is this okay?  Method 1: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another

Comment: Your question in the comments is quite different than your original question, of whether or not you should copy your home folder when moving from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. The Method 1 link above is one way to do what you want, but a lot of people use the `dd` command as well. You should really post a new question, because that is how AskUbuntu works. Others will not see questions in the comments section (unless they happen to click on your original question and read the comments), so you will miss getting input from experts familiar with your new question.

Comment: Another option for you is to: (1) Reinstall all the software you want (which I assume is manageable and is not a lot of applications). (2) Then copy your files (Documents, Pictures, Music, etc.). (3) Then, copy your settings from your first Ubuntu 20.04 to your new 20.04. This will work because both versions are the same; see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056392/100356) on how to do that. However, others may suggest different options for you or point you to an existing question, if you ask a new question.